# How to add DATA-(something) attribute to .class element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried to add data-attribute to class element ( .class ) using this code:

```
$(".class").data("attribute") === "" ;
```

and later with this

```
$(".class").attr('data-sr','');
```

But that dont work at all. Option1 dont work at all, and option2 work only for tag names in my case.
Is something bugged or I am not using something good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly assign and read data attributes using jQuery's .data() as follows:

```
// Assign a data attribute
$(selector).data('my-attr', 'test value');

// Read a data attribute
var value = $(selector).data('my-attr');
```

If you want the data attributes added to the DOM itself, you would use jQuery's attr() as follows:

```
// Assign a data attribute - note the need to prefix it with "data-"
$(selector).attr('data-my-attr', 'test value');

// Read a data attribute - note the need to prefix it with "data-"
var value = $(selector).attr('data-my-attr');
```

Examples:

```
$(function() {
    // This value is stored in the jQuery cache object
    $(".testclass").data('val', 'something1');
    alert($(".testclass").data('val'));

    // Alternatively, this value is stored on the DOM element itself
    $(".testclass").attr('data-val', 'something2');
    alert($(".testclass").attr('data-val'));
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/hau9gac9/

Answer (score 0):

Just like `.attr()`, you give two arguments to change the data:

```
$(".class").data("attribute", "value");
```

Note that if you add the data with `.data` rather than `.attr`, it stores it internally within jQuery, you won't see it as a `data-attribute` attribute in the DOM. jQuery only uses the `data-attribute` attribute as an initial source of the value the first time you read it.